# Using wget to download images and saving with specified filename

Tags: linux, wget, imagedownload

I'm using wget mac terminal to download images from a file where each image url is it's own line, and that works perfectly with this command:

```
    cut -f1 -d, images.txt | while read url; do wget ${url} -O $(basename ${url}); done
```

However I want to specify the output filename it's saved as instead of using the basename. The file name is specified in the next column, separated by either space or comma and I can't quite figure out how to tell wget to use the 2nd column as the name it should as the -O name.

I'm sure it's a simple change to my above command but after reading dozens of different posts on here and other sites I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Better provide sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use whitespace as the seperator it's very easy:

```
cat images.txt | while read url name; do wget ${url} -O ${name}; done
```

Explanation: instead of reading just one variable per line (`${url}`) as in your example, you read two (`${url}` and `${name}`). The second one is your local filename. I assumed your `images.txt` file looks something like this:

```
http://cwsmgmt.corsair.com/newscripts/landing-pages/wallpaper/v3/Wallpaper-v3-2560x1440.jpg test.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks @McCavity!! That worked exactly the way I needed it to! Obviously I was missing the input of reading the name and that's what I couldn't figure out how/where to add it.  After reading your command and where you added the name makes perfect sense now. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Be mindful of the `while read`, though. `while read` will always read exactly the number of variables you provided. That means if you have a file like this:

    foo1 foo2 foo3
    bar1
    baz1 baz2 baz3 baz4

and you use `while read var1 var2 var3` you'd get:

    var1='foo1' var2='foo2' var3='foo3'
    var1='bar1' var2='' var3=''
    var1='baz1' var2='baz2' var3='baz3 baz4'

i.e. if you have whitespace in your data may run into problems. You should use whitespace *only* as the separator in your file or use a different delimiter and IFS (Internal Field Separator).